# MySQL load data infile ; incorrect string value error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, load-data-infile

I am using MySQL workbench to create database from EER diagram (forward engineering),
and want to load data from a text file to my table

```
load data infile 'c:\\actors.txt' ignore into table actors field terminated by '\t';
```

the file contains European characters. I have tried utf16,utf8,latin1,latin2 character sets for my database but still receiving error ***incorrect string value*** '\xE4vel'. I have dropped schema and created each time with different character set (all tables have correct collate according to character set). my os is windows7 64bit if it makes any difference!
any one can help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it , it seems that workbench (***at least in my case***) does not define charset and collate of each column in tables as it is defined in the database and you should do it manually!!
for example if you set your database charset latin1 and collate latin1_swedish_ci each field in each table still remains empty of charset and collate , I had to go 1 by 1 to my tables and set the columns charset ! I dont know if it is the problem of forward engineering or what ?
any way it solved

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Also, I don't know what is with the random Ignore after your file location.

For instance, you would just add the word LOCAL after Data, and take out the ignore. Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\actors.txt' into table actors field terminated by '\t';
```

Comment: that ignore works kinda like local , ignores errors (doesn't stop loading) and continue the rest. I tried local and still the same problem, all the special characters are replaced by ? in the database

Comment: Hmmm, very strange.  Special characters as in what? And what are you going to use this data as later? You might need to transfer the special characters to HTML code, save it like that, then when using it, transfer it back.

Comment: characters like ö,ä,å,á,Ó,...  this is a simple movie database with tables of actors directors writers producers and ...

Comment: Try using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, so for instance, `mysqli_real_escape_string($data)`